# AVAudioPlayer issue leads to app crashes

Tags: ios, swift, audio, initialization

I am making an audio player just for a test for my other projects.
I defined a class named `BackgroundAudio` as following:

```
class BackgroundAudio: NSObject,AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override init() {
    super.init()

}

func play(audioOfUrl:URL) {


    let urlPath = audioOfUrl

    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: urlPath)
        audioPlayer.delegate = self
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func stop() {
    audioPlayer.stop()
}

func mute() {
    audioPlayer.setVolume(0, fadeDuration: 2)
}

func unMute() {
    audioPlayer.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 2)
}
}
```

In my View Controller, I initialized the class and implement a few relevant function by doing this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Focus", withExtension: "mp3")!
var backgroundAudio:BackgroundAudio?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    backgroundAudio = BackgroundAudio()
}

@IBAction func playButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    backgroundAudio?.play(audioOfUrl: urlPath)
}

@IBAction func stopButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    backgroundAudio?.stop()
}

@IBAction func muteButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    backgroundAudio?.mute()
}

@IBAction func unMuteButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

}
}
```

Everything works quite fine but issues raised. The issue is this:

If I clicked the `play` button and it works, but if I press `mute` button, the program crashes. is it because the class is not initialized when the mute is pressed before the play button pressed. 
[image]

How to resolve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: try checking `if audioPlayer.isPlaying`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in your mute function you could check for the existence of the audioplyer URL and if it is nil just return. Something like:

```
if audioPlayer.url != nil { do Stuff } else { do nothing }
```

Comment: I just figure out the instance was not initialized before I call the mute method. And your approach actually help me resolving another issue. thanks man